# In WSL enviroment, what is the difference between disk c and other disk?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using apache2+php7.2 on WSL. When I tried to change the `uploaded_tmp_dir` in `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini` into an path in /mnt/d, I got error like this:

```
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Operation not permitted in
```

strace info:

```
247   unlink("./uploaded_files/avatar \346\227\240\345\220\215.jpg") = 0
247   rename("/mnt/d/contents/test/tmp/phpe68vM3", "uploaded_files/avatar \345\246\271\345\255\220\343\200\202\343\200\202.jpg") = 0
247   umask(077)                        = 022
247   umask(022)                        = 077
247   chmod("uploaded_files/avatar \345\246\271\345\255\220\343\200\202\343\200\202.jpg", 0644) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

However, if I set an path in /mnt/c, it's Ok.
I think there are some differences between /mnt/c and /mnt/d.
Could someone please tell me what to do with this?

Comment: Can you provide more info about that error "Operation not permitted in"? for example, strace, ptrace, windows event log etc.

Comment: @Biswapriyo here is strace info (added)o_o

Comment: Try with `chown` in that path.